# Sometimes a vue router-link refreshes / reloads the page. Sometimes it doesn't

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nginx, vue-router

I noticed some strange behaviour when clicking some router-links on the "itemcarousel" of my homepage :

http://www.leefschooldewonderwijzer.be

When you just click the first carousel item (girl with magnify glass), the corresponding page loads without refreshing the browser. However, when you first click the arrow left (so item slides to the right) and then the same item, the browser first refreshes/reloads.

I checked the HTML and really nothing changed in the actual link after clicking the arrows:

```
<a href="/article/33" class="inneritem" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://wonderwijzer.fast-focus.be/uploads/wonderwijzer/imageasset/source/11/version_500x500_bigstock--140862161.jpg&quot;); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;" tabindex="0"><h2 class="itemtitle">
              Buitenonderwijs
            </h2></a>
```

Does anyone have a clue why this is happening ? I'm getting the same behaviour with some other links as well.

=> the second news post under "in de kijker". When you click "lees meer" => refresh as well

Some routes open correctly, others do an unwanted refresh.

**Update**

It must have something to do with history mode. When I deploy the website
with hash mode, it works properly. I'm using Nginx as webserver. Could there be something wrong in server config ?

```
server {
  listen 80;

  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_proxied any;

  root /webroot/wonderwijzer.be;
  index index.html;

  server_name 
  leefschooldewonderwijzer.be 
  www.leefschooldewonderwijzer.be;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    # Some basic cache-control for static files to be sent to the browser
    expires max;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the a tag use the vue router tag

```
<router-link to="/article/33"> Buitenonderwijs </router-link>
```

this will load the view without reloading the website

Comment: Actually, I'm already doing this in my code. So this is not the solution.
               <router-link
                  class="inneritem"
                  :to="carouselitem.article.length > 0 ? { path: getArticleUrl(carouselitem.article[0].id) } : '' "
                  :style="itemStyle(carouselitem)"
                >
                    {{ carouselitem.text.value_nl }}
                </router-link>

Answer (score 0):

This also happens to me sometimes when I use Quasar Vue router. it only happens in dev, not build